# How should I share filtering logic between multiple LINQ-where clauses?

Tags: c#, linq

Let `A` be a class whith some property `Hello`. I would like to filter collections of `A` instances by this property in many places. Thus I'd make somewhere a static member of type `Expression<Func<A, bool>>` which denotes the filtering predicate and I use it in all places where I do a filtering. (This predicate would be transformed by an ORM to some concrete DB-specific expression.)

Next. There exists a class `B` with property of type `A`. I would like to filter collection of `B` instances by the same logic as was used in the first case (by property `Hello` of class `A`).

**Question**. What is the most correct way to implement this and reduce code duplication?

**My suggestion**. Add three things: 1) interface `IWithA` with property of type `A`, 2) class `WithA<T>` implementing this interface `IWithA` and providing property of type `T`, 3) some static property of type `Expression<Func<IWithA, bool>>` implementing the filtering logic. Demo code is following.

```
    public static void Main() {
        var listOfAs = new List<A>().AsQueryable();
        var query0 = listOfAs
            .Select(a => new WithA<A> {
                A = a,
                Smth = a,
            })
            .Where(Filter);
        var listOfBs = new List<B>().AsQueryable();
        var query1 = listOfBs
            .Select(b => new WithA<B> {
                A = b.A,
                Smth = b,
            })
            .Where(Filter);
    }

    private class A {
        public int Hello { get; set; }
    }

    private class B {
        public A A { get; set; }
    }

    private interface IWithA {
        A A { get; set; }
    }

    private class WithA<T> : IWithA {
        public A A { get; set; }
        public T Smth { get; set; }
    }

    private static readonly Expression<Func<IWithA, bool>> Filter = a => a.A.Hello > 0;
```

The problem with this approach: 1) one must always make `Select(x => new WithA<X> { ... })`, 2) the ORM may not support this.

**About the answer**. I am satisfied with the accepted answer (by Ivan Stoev). I think it is the best possible approach. Also it is helpful to look at the suggestion from Mihail Stancescu (see it in comments to the question). Still I do not understand the answer from user853710; may be it is useful also.

Comment: I would use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) so I don't have to always write `Select(x => new WithA<X> { ... })` and [EFDynamicGlobalFilters](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) to achieve global and dynamic filters for this.

Comment: @MihailStancescu How would you use AutoMapper? I would write somewhere before query: `Mapper.Initialize(x => x.CreateMap<B, IWithA>().ConvertUsing((B b) => new WithA<B> { A = b.A, Smth = b, }));` and in query - `.Select(x => Mapper.Map<IWithA>(x))`. Do you know if the modern ORMs support this and translate to DB-specific expression?

Comment: If you have mappings defined for Automapper there is an extension method you can use for your queries like this `query.ProjectTo<ViewModel>();`. More info [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create and use a helper function that converts the original `Expression<A, bool>` to `Expression<B, bool>` using the `System.Linq.Expressions` like this

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<TTarget, bool>> ConvertTo<TSource, TTarget>(this Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> source, Expression<Func<TTarget, TSource>> sourceSelector)
    {
        var body = new ParameterExpressionReplacer { source = source.Parameters[0], target = sourceSelector.Body }.Visit(source.Body);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TTarget, bool>>(body, sourceSelector.Parameters);
        return lambda;
    }

    class ParameterExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression source;
        public Expression target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == source ? target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage

```
Expression<Func<A, bool>> filterA = item => item.Hello == 2; // The original logic
var filterB = filterA.ConvertTo((B b) => b.A);
```

This approach doesn't require any changes to your entity model. Of course you can cache the filters in a static properties of the respective classes if you wish, but the principle is still write the logic in one place and then just use convert in other places.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to reinvent the wheel. Take a look at the Library [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)
The Predicatebuilder is what you need and it gives you much more. Albahari (The developer) has amazing products and libraries for sharing and give you much fun using threm

Comment: This isn't really an answer. You should add this as a comment under the question. Alternatively you could show some code to explain how `PredicateBuilder` can be used to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I do not agree with you. The link I provided gives those code Examples, more than enough. It would be an unnecessary duplication of work. but gives Hoborg the solution to his problem

Comment: It is a very necessary duplication of work. One of the principles of Stack Overflow is that the answers should stand alone if the link becomes broken. Take a read of this on meta - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/144156. You really need to provide the content in the answer, and not only as a link.

Comment: I have taken a look on on your link, but cannot understand how it can help with my question. Would you be so kind to give me a clue? I agree with @Enigmativity in such point that it is very inconvenient to search for a solution in the provided web page. Excuse me for the delay.